# Python: Create data-frame of size 12 from a data set of 300 such that it contain 0:12, 1:13, 2:14 and so on

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a data frame with over 300 rows, I wish to extract 12 sized data frame like: 0:12, 1:13, 2:14, 3:15 and so on like a moving window and store each in a data frame.

I have tried getting this manually but it would take great deal of time to do so in the below fashion:

```
dfa=df3[:12]
dfb=df3[1:13]
dfc=df3[2:14]
dfd=df3[3:15]
dfe=df3[4:16]
dff=df3[5:17]
dfg=df3[6:18]
dfh=df3[7:19]
dfi=df3[8:20]
dfj=df3[9:21]
dfk=df3[10:22]
dfl=df3[11:23]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try using `for` loop?

Comment: better use list or dictionary instead of `dfa` `dfb`, etc. ie. `all_df = []` and then you can do `for x in range(12): all_df.append(df3[x:x+12])`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You can use a loop iterating from 0 to the length of your dataframe's row - your expected dataframe partition length. Like if you have 300 rows in your dataframe, iterate between range of `0,300-11`. Then append the partition to a list initiated before.

```py
new_list = [[]]
for i in range(df.shape[0]-11):
    new_list.append([df[i:i+12]])
#delete the first index of list which is []
del new_list[0]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension to get array of dataframes as your desire

```py
size = 12
dfs = [df[i:i+size] for i in range(len(df)-size+1)]
```